# Filtering based on abap timestamp fails

Tags: odata, sapui5, abap, sap-gateway

I have an Odata Service where there is a field for ABAP Timestamp in ***Edm.Decimal*** format. Now when I try to filter the data between a given time frame, it is failing with error ( 400 ).

Example: I tried to filter the data from 01-03-2022 to 16-03-2022.
Error : `/odata/app/ZROOT_C?$skip=0&$top=20&$orderby=pickup_tstmp%20desc&$filter=pickup_tstmp%20ge%202022030100m%20and%20pickup_tstmp%20le%20202203162359m`

```
[{"code":"/IWBEP/CM_MGW_RT/010","message":"'Change the format for the date (2022030100) in the time specification'.","persistent":false,"targets":["/ZTMSCCROOT_C"],"type":"Error"},
```

Is there any format change need to be done, before filtering ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why don't you use Edm.DateTime?

Comment: @Marc it is already a standard field which I can change

Answer (score 1):

Why do you decide to use EDM.Decimal for a timestamp, the error simply states gateway can't handle the time using EDM.Decimal. Please change to use Edm.DateTime in your service definition and test again.

Regards,
Derek

Answer (score 0):

In ABAP timestamp has 14 numbers: YYYYMMDDHHmmss

Or may be not enough 00 in first value:

1st: 2022030100m => 2022.03.01 00m <- ???

2nd: 202203162359m => 2022.03.16 23:59m

Comment: The EDM.Decimal field is having length of 15